# Talking to several USB modems from java

Tags: java, sms

I wish to connect 10 usb modems to a windows/linux pc and send AT comments to them to send sms and receive sms from them. Is this possible in Java?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is possible. You just have to know the COMM port ID for each modem. I do not know pure java way to discover these IDs. So, you need some platform specific way (e.g. WMI on windows or some command on Unix). But once you have ID it should not be a problem.

Comment: Are you saying that when you connect a USB device to a computer it gets a COMM port ID?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the USB modem implements a serial interface, it should get a COMM port id. If so, you can use [RXTX](http://users.frii.com/jarvi/rxtx/index.html) to talk to the model.

Answer (score 1):

afaik, you can use serial communication while talking to usb devices as long as device hardware contains an ftdi chip or so. I used a c++ serial lib in a Qt project, talking to an Arduino connected on a usb port. arduino appears as a com device.

otherwise, you may look at the jusb project: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-usb/index.html